# UnknownAttributeError on Heroku but not local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Getting an `UnknownAttributeError` when trying to create a model instance in production. Works fine locally, but not on Heroku.

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'team_id' for Membership
```

After a user signs up, the first thing they do is create a team. If the team saves, then teams#create makes them a member of that team.

```
Membership.create(user_id: current_user.id, team_id: @team.id )
```

Team `has_many :users, through: :memberships` and User `has_many :teams, through: :memberships`.

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :team_id, presence: true
end
```

Even looks like `team_id` is on the `Membership` table on Heroku, so I am very confused...

```
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1)  [["version", "20150502213611"]]
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
Migrating to CreateMemberships (20150502215929)
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
== 20150502215929 CreateMemberships: migrating ================================
-- create_table(:memberships)
   (7.4ms)  CREATE TABLE "memberships" ("id" serial primary key, "user_id" integer, "team_id" integer, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL) 
   -> 0.0079s
== 20150502215929 CreateMemberships: migrated (0.0080s) =======================
```

Again, no problems locally, only on Heroku.

Running Rails 4.2.1

Comment: output of `rake db:migrate:status` in Heroku? Show the output of `Membership.column_names`....

Comment: In the heroku console
irb(main):002:0> Membership.new
=> #<Membership id: nil, user_id: nil, team_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Answer (score 2):

I had the same unknownattribute error despite the attribute clearly existing in my model. As far as I can tell it's an error from heroku's end. I fixed it with:

```
heroku restart
```

Answer (score 0):

This magically started working a minute ago. No idea why.